# How do I retrieve shipping classes per variation to show in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to show different shipping times per product in my webshop. Currently I am using the following code. Which works fine for simple products. But it does not get the shipping classes of my variations in the product:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'show_shipping_cart', 2 );
 function show_shipping_cart() {

$product_classes = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_shipping_class' );

if ( $product_classes && ! is_wp_error ( $product_classes ) ){
    $single_class = array_shift( $product_classes ); ?>

    <p class="shipping_class_desc"><?php echo 'Levertijd: '.$single_class->description; ?></p><?php
    }
}
```

How do I get the function to retrieve the shipping classes from the variations in the product to show in the front-end? Instead of showing the shipping class from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get product variation. You can get using `get_visible_children()` function. try the below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'show_shipping_cart', 2 );
function show_shipping_cart() {

    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_ID() );

    // Loop through the visible variations IDs 
    foreach ( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ) {
        // Get the variation shipping class WP_Term object
        $shipping_classes = wp_get_post_terms( $variation_id, 'product_shipping_class' )[0]; 
        if( $shipping_classes ){ ?>
            <p class="shipping_class_desc"><?php echo 'Levertijd: '.$shipping_classes->description; ?></p>
        <?php }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is getting there. Now it shows all the classes below each other on the frond-end instead of the one selected. Do you know how to make it, so it'll only show the shipping class of the selected variation and hide the other?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it will require more code and customization for that.